# Inverse derivative problem

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The functions $b$ and $q$ are inverses of each other. At each point $(x,y)$ on the graph of $b$, the derivative is equal to $3y^2+4y+3$. At which $x$-values is the derivative of $q$ equal to $1/2$?

---

I ultimately don't know how to start or finish this problem. I've tried calculating the antiderivative of $3y^2 + 4y + 3$, and it is $y^3 + 2y^2 + 3y + C$. However, I don't know how I would go about ascertaining the roots to $y^3 + 2y^2 + 3y - \frac{1}{2} = 0.$ Furthermore, I'm not sure if solving this equation would even be the correct approach.

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by derivative? Is it the total derivative? Or a partial derivative w.r.t. one of the variables?

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $b$ is $y$ vs $x$. The graph of $q$ is $x$ vs $y$ - ie the same grah but with the axes switched.

If the gradient at some point on the graph for $b$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}=m$ then at the same point on the graph for $q$ the gradient will be $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{m}$. When the gradient of $q$ is $\frac12$ the gradient of $b$ will be $2$.

Set $$3y^2+4y+3=2$$ $$3y^2+4y+1=(3y+1)(y+1)=0$$ $$y=-\frac13, -1$$

Since $q$ is the same graph as $b$ but with the axes switched, these $y$ values for $b$ are the same as the $x$ values that are required for $q$.